# Mule adding value to xml

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I am using Mule to take input using a html file and using the input to add the value to an xml i am able to extract the value i just need to add it in the xml further, How should i proceed further,any help will be appreciated 
Here is my config

```
<flow name="webappFlow1" doc:name="webappFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="submitData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map"/>
    <logger message="#[payload['VendorId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="vendorId" value="#[payload['VendorId']]"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File"/>

</flow>
```

The next step would be to add the vendor id to the xml file 
if the xml looks like

```
<import>
  <field></field>
</import>
```

I want to add value in field
Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wrestling Studio in submission is an issue, you can always use an expression component to read a file.

I notice that you intend to read from `src/test/resources`: Studio doesn't put this path on the classpath, so assuming you're OK with reading files from `src/main/app` instead, the following component would read `src/main/app/text.xml`:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Read Classpath Resource">
  payload = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream('test.xml')
</expression-component>
```

Comment: I have used object to xml transformation to get the xml anyway thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

The first thing it is important to understand when you first approach mule is that message sources (i.e. inbound endpoint) can be only placed at the beginning of the flow. After them any element should be a message processor. You can find more details [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Message+Sources+and+Message+Processors)

That said your use case can be easily implemented either with a custom component or by using the [fileutil module](http://javaduke.github.com/mule-module-file-utils/mule/fileutils.html)

Your flow would look like the following:

```
<flow name="webappFlow1" doc:name="webappFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="submitData" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer doc:name="Body to Parameter Map"/>
<logger message="#[payload['VendorId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
    <add-message-property key="vendorId" value="#[payload['VendorId']]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<set-variable variableName="VendorId" value="#[payload['VendorId']]"/>
<file-utils:read-file fileName="import.xml" filePath="/my/path" />
<!-- The following trasformer should be a either some custom java code or a scripting transformer 
 that process the payload (the xmlFile) and by processing it i adds the flowVar['vendorId'] to it. -->
<trasformer ref="xmlTrasformer" />
</flow>
```

You can find information about how to write transformer [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Transformers) and [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Script+Transformer+Reference)

Comment: Hi genjosanzo thanks for your reply,the file-utils is not bound as my studio cannot detect it and the schema cant be found on browser but github is there a workaround for that?

Comment: If you clone the project and you package it via maven, it will generate an update site zip that you can install in Studio

Comment: @genjosanzo I didn't know about file-utils, that's quite a useful module!